# ShieldUI Grid-conditional formatting issue

Tags: gridview, datagridview, grid, shieldui

How do I change a cell's value, using conditional formatting, where the cell may be in a different position each time the grid is loaded?

https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/conditional-formatting

I have columns that are not in the data so they end up with a value of null. 
I want to replace that with blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [columnTemplate](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/columnTemplate) option is what you need.

You can define your column like this:

```
{ 
    field: "unknown", title: "Unknown", 
    columnTemplate: function(cell, item, index) { return item || ""; } 
}
```